# mongoose instance methods are showing different results

Tags: javascript, mongoose, methods, instance, koa

i'm currently making a server with javascript, koa, and mongoose.
i made two different mongoose instance methods, which receives password from JSON body
and hashes it with bcrypt, saves it on a 'hashedPassword' on user.

Initially, i wrote the second setPassword function (which uses promise, 'then' methods.),
but when the user document saved, the 'hashedPassword' property didn't showed up.

so i tried with first one, it worked well and user document has saved with hashedPassword.

[image: two documents using two different user instance methods]

although these two instance methods looks similar, i wonder why these methods leads to different result.. please help

```js
 import mongoose from "mongoose";
    import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      username: String,
      hashedPassword: String,
    });

    UserSchema.methods.setPassword = async function (password) {
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      this.hashedPassword = hash;
    };


// UserSchema.methods.setPassword = async function (password) {
//   bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
//     this.hashedPassword = hash;
//   });
// };
// this code didn't save the hashed

    const User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);

    export default User;
```

user controller would be like this

```js
    const register = async (ctx) => {
    
    const { username, password } = ctx.request.body;
    try {
      const user = new User({
        username,
      });
      await user.setPassword(password);
      await user.save();
    catch(e) { ctx.throw(500,e) }
    }
```

Comment: Using `.then()` doesn't negate the use for `await` in this case. This is fundamentally an issue of not fully understanding promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a mongoose-specific issue, you need to revise your understanding of how promises work.

Adding `await` before `bcrypt.hash` in the commented-out code should make it work, but there is no reason for you here to prefer `.then` over `await`.

In the second example, `setPassword` only fires the hashing process and doesn't ask the caller to wait until the hashing is done, and then adds the hashed password to the document, while the first one does.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just thought the code
 `await user.setPassword(password)`
 waits for the function to set the hashedPassword, but this outside `await` seems useless at all.

Comment: You need to `await` inside and outside.

Comment: oh..then the outside `await` code waits until the setPassword function executes the whole code and returns a promise?

Comment: any async function returns a promise immediately, using `await` inside the async function makes it resolve when all the work inside it is done.

`await myAsyncFunction()` makes the caller wait for all the asynchronous tasks inside.

I'd recommend reading up on callbacks/promises/async-await.
If you want to be an expert in JS, I'd recommend reading You Don't Know JavaScript Yet by Kyle Simpson. It has been a great help for me to truly understand JS.

Comment: i understood a little bit now. i sure have to study more about JS thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach using schema built-in methods:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
        if (this.isModified('hashedPassword')) {
            this.hashedPassword= await bcrypt.hash(this.hashedPassword, 10)
        }

        next()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pre-save function inside the schema like that :

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  // Only if password was moddified
  if (!this.isModified('hashedPassword')) return next();
  // then Hash password
  this.hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.hashedPassword, 10);
  next();
});
```